# Any way to create a gear+chain, like for a bike?

Tags: building, gears, wheel

I would like to create a LEGO bike. I can imagine how most of it would work, but i'm stuck at the chain.

I need a way for the turning pedals (at one spot) to cause the wheel (in the back) to spin with them. A design like the classic bike chain would be nice, but something else that does the job would also work.

It would be best if a solution uses standard pieces, but i do have a few special pieces.

Comment: Is this a human-size riding bike, or a smaller scale model?

Comment: A model. I sure don't have enough pieces to do a human size one. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like LEGO sells [chain and sprockets](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00G1OURZ2), don't know if you'd have them lying around though.

You could also try using pulleys instead. If you don't have any of the actual pulleys, take the tread off of two wheels and stretch a rubber band across, that should work too.

[image: Lego Pulleys]

Comment: Good idea about the wheels. I'll try that, and then get back to you.

Comment: Perfect! Just a note, i had to use those 4-part sticks in a regular round hole, or else it wouldn't turn. I had at first used a double part stick, half round and half split, but the round part fit too tightly to spin.

Comment: I'd suggest that the Link Treads are probably a little wide for a bike, the Link Chain that Ambo100 mentions would be better, but rubber bands are easier to obtain.

Answer (score 4):

The Technic [Riding Cycle](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=S&catString=36.682.225) theme features several bikes that may be of inspiration. One particular set [Moto Cross Bike (42007)](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=42007-1) uses several  [3711: Technic, Link Chain](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3711) parts to make a chain.

[image]

Based on [Bricklink prices for the last six months](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogPG.asp?P=3711&colorID=11), 39 chain pieces (the amount shown in the set above) would cost £4.29 (Aprox. $6.91 or €1.26).

Pulleys and rubber bands are generally more commonly found in sets but they don't tend to provide as much traction as a gear and chain.

Comment: I agree that a real gear and chain would work best, but i was looking to do it with common pieces that i already have, like in ihavnoclue's answer. Thanks anyways.