# Is it possible to create your own wheel?

Tags: building, manufacturing, wheel

After my [other question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/4608/any-way-to-create-a-gearchain-like-for-a-bike), i pretty much have a bicycle design all planned. My problem now is with wheels.

None of my LEGO wheels are big enough to work on a bike. And, the biggest ones are all pretty fat.

I was wondering if it would be possible to simulate my own wheels, that i could then attach to a LEGO creation.

It doesn't have to be made out of only LEGOs; i'm open to other building toys and materials as well.

Answer (score 7):

You can always brick-build a wheel.  The curved slope pieces can closely approximate a circle.

For example, 12 [4x1 curved slopes](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=61678) gives a circle with a radius of 160 [LDUs](http://www.ldraw.org/article/218.html#ldu) (8 studs).

For more information on brick-built wheels, I suggest you refer to the "Brick Built LEGO Wheels Book":

[image]

http://www.ultimate-design.org/2014/05/unofficial-free-brick-built-lego-wheels.html